# Is there a graphic tool to display (and maybe change) elasticsearch mappings?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head,
which is awesome (!), but it does not have that functionality.

After putting several mapping into the index, I'd like to be able to view them graphically. Is that possible?

Comment: No, I'm not aware of a tool that allows you to do this.  ES Head lets you look at the JSON representation of the mapping ("Info" > "Metadata" dropdown on the index).  I have visual mapping and editing on the roadmap for Inquisitor (https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor), but it's not done yet.

Comment: great! thanks!!!
Where would you publish it when you are done?

Comment: I'll probably announce it on the ES mailing list when the feature is ready.  If I remember, I'll add a comment on this post too.

Comment: Oh, just so you know, you can't change a field's type once it's been mapped, only add new fields.  So if that is what you are looking for, it's a limitation of ES and not any tool :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make new indexes, with new mappings. I've used this to translate logstash mappings from one type to another. I have used [this reindex plugin](https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch-reindex) to much success. It makes the streaming one index into another much simpler and takes essentially only 2 http requests.

Something like this:

```
$ curl -XPOST http://elnode:9200/<New Index Name> -d @<new mapping>.json
$ curl -XPUT  http://elnode:9200/<New Index Name>/logs/_reindex\?searchIndex=<Old Index Name>\&searchType=logs
```

Now you have a new index of new mapping with old index's data. You could then delete the old and make an alias with the old index's name that points to the new.

A bit of work, but I'd needed it for keeping old logstash data in a new format.